# reset all changed model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to reset all the changes done in memory to a model instance after it was retrieved from the database.

I've found that there are methods to reset each attribute one by one, (like @user.reset_username!) but I cannot find anything to reset all at the same time to the original state.

How could I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try @user.reload method

Answer (score 0):

To simply reset all dirty attributes without hitting the database, you can use `@user.restore_attributes`, or use `@user.restore_column_name` to reset a single attribute.